# Stopping an animated gif within 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, animated-gif

I have the following code to "freeze" a gif within 5 seconds, however the gif stops as soon as the window.onLoad event is fired:

```
[].slice.apply(document.images).filter(is_gif_image).map(freeze_gif);

function is_gif_image(i) {
    return /^(?!data:).*\.gif/i.test(i.src);
}

function freeze_gif(i) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var w = c.width = i.width;
    var h = c.height = i.height;
    c.getContext('2d').drawImage(i, 0, 0, w, h);
    try {
        i.src = c.toDataURL("image/gif"); 
    } catch(e) { 
        for (var j = 0, a; a = i.attributes[j]; j++)
            c.setAttribute(a.name, a.value);
        i.parentNode.replaceChild(c, i);
    }
}

window.onLoad = function(){
  var gifs = freeze_gif(i);
  setTimeout( function() {
   gifs[n].click();
 }, 5000);
}
```

Is it correct to include the setTimeout in window.onLoad? I have tried to include it in the freeze_gif(i), but the gif keeps stopping when the event is fired up. Can you help?

Thank you

**EDIT 1:**
As rightly recommended, I am including a working example of the current code:

https://jsfiddle.net/rqfdkkgz/

Comment: Please provide a working example (real demo the show the problem)

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing that out. I have just included the jsfiddle

Comment: check the answer i added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are running this line at start:

```
[].slice.apply(document.images).filter(is_gif_image).map(freeze_gif);
```

And it freezing all of your images.

The problem with jsfiddle is that all the javascript code there is already inside `window.load` so you can't really use it twice, but here is the same inside snippet:

```js
function is_gif_image(i) {
  return /^(?!data:).*\.gif/i.test(i.src);
}

function freeze_gif(i) {
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  var w = c.width = i.width;
  var h = c.height = i.height;
  c.getContext('2d').drawImage(i, 0, 0, w, h);
  try {
    i.src = c.toDataURL("image/gif"); 
  } catch(e) { 
    for (var j = 0, a; a = i.attributes[j]; j++)
      c.setAttribute(a.name, a.value);
    i.parentNode.replaceChild(c, i);
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    [].slice.apply(document.images).filter(is_gif_image).map(freeze_gif);
  }, 5000);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://rubentd.com/img/banana.gif" alt="" >
```

I moved the first line (that cases the freeze of all the gif images) inside the setTimeout function.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. Really new to Javascript and did not know about jsfiddle already putting the code in the window.onload. Thanks

Comment: Well... this wasn't really your problem there :)